# how can i use securityUtility --encoding=custom in WAS Liberty 8.5.5.9?

Tags: java, security, encryption, websphere, websphere-liberty

I am using WAS Liberty version 8.5.5.9 (with license) and implementing CustomPasswordEncryption class to do encryption and decryption.

I tried to follow as per below link from IBM:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_developing_custom_passwd_encrypt.html

I checked in log that custom feature is updated sucessfully.

When i try to run securityUtility encode --encoding=custom. I'm getting error : com.ibm.websphere.crypto.UnsupoortedCryptoAlgorithmException and encoding is not support.

I tried to run in development version (17.0.0.4) and it's working fine.

Anyone know what i am missing in order to run at 8.5.5.9 version?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the exception contents.  Is your encrypt method being called when you invoke securityUtility?  Can you successfully invoke YourCustomPwdUtility.encrypt from an application?

Comment: Hi @F Rowe, Exception is as follow: com.ibm.websphere.crypto.UnsupportedCryptoAlgorithmException  at com.ibm.websphere.crypto.PasswordUtil.encode(PasswordUtil.java:191) at com.ibm.ws.security.utility.tasks.EncodeTask.encode(EncodeTask.java:131) <br/>

Comment: at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.cmdline.UtilityMain.main(UtilityMain.java:42)    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.cmdline.Main.main(Main.java:52)                         Error: com.ibm.websphere.crypto.UnsuportedCryptoAlgorithmException      I deploy and run same program at version 17.0.0.4 and it's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom password encryption is not supported in 8.5.5.9. It was introduced in 16.0.0.2. I would strongly suggest upgrading to 17.0.0.4 at this stage. It is the most recent fixpack available, and 8.5.5.9 goes out of iFix coverage at the end of March this year.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair. Do you know if i can upgrade from 8.5.5.9 to 17.0.0.4? Is there have any charges?

Comment: Liberty has zero migration as long as you don’t change the config it should work without any changes.

Comment: Hi Alasdair, Is there link in IBM site saying that custom password encryption is not supported in 8.5.5.9? i couldn't find it. thanks

Comment: We don’t maintain that kind of documentation. Normally we would tag to indicate when it was introduced, but I went and checked our version control which is why I know it isn’t in 8.5.5.9. It was added in 16.0.0.2. As I said you should be looking to upgrade anyway. There are security fixes you don’t have and iFix support ends for 8.5.5.9 in March.

Comment: Hi Alasdair, Thanks Regards, Kevin

Comment: Hi Alasdair, would like to check with you if you might know..If i upgrade from 8.5.5.9 to 17.0.0.4 do i need to buy new license or can use with existing licenese? Thanks

Comment: No need to buy a new license. We changed the versioning scheme after 8.5.5.9 to be date based. The major version is now the year of release, but otherwise 16.0.0.2 was just the next fixpack after 8.5.5.9.